# Printing input values from array of hashes

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to only print the values given but the input.
If I print November, only print the students that their cohort is in November

I tried student.fetch(cohort_input).include?(months) 
but doesn't work.
I've been told that I needed to create a list of the months to check

````
months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]

def input_students
  puts "Please enter the names of the students"
  puts "To finish, just hit return twice"
  students = []
  while name = gets.chomp do
    break if name.empty?
    puts "What is your student cohort"
    cohort = gets.chomp
    puts "Where is your student from"
    country_of_birth = gets.chomp
    if cohort.empty? || country_of_birth.empty?
      cohort = "Not given"
      country_of_birth = "(Not given)"
    end
    students << {name: name, cohort: cohort, country_of_birth: country_of_birth}
    if students.count > 1
      puts "Now we have #{students.count} students"
    else
      puts "Now we have #{students.count} student"
    end
    puts "Enter another name"
  end
  students
end

def print_header
puts "The students of Villains Academy"
puts "-------------"
end



def print(students)
puts "What cohort would you like to print"
  cohort_input = gets.chomp#.capitalize
  students.map do |student|
    student.map {|k,v| [k, v.to_sym]
  }
  #puts " #{student[:name]} (#{student[:cohort]} cohort), #{student[:country_of_birth]}"
  end
  students.each do |student|
    if cohort_input == months[]
      puts student[:name]
    end
  end
end


def print_footer(students)
  if students.count > 1
    puts "Overall, we have #{students.count} great students"
  else
    puts "Overall, we have #{students.count} great student"
  end
end

students = input_students
print_header
print(students)
print_footer(students)```

All kind of errors
````

Comment: "Only in cohort X" usually translates in Ruby as "use `select` on an array".

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: You are overwriting the core method [Kernel#print](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Kernel.html#method-i-print)!

Comment: Sorry, is the first time I post something and I just started coding , on top of that English is not even my first language.

Comment: If your code "doesn't work" an exception is raised or the object returned or displayed is not what you want. Which is it? Elaborate (by editing). If an exception is raised what is the error message and on which line does the error occur? Newbies often undervalue error messages. They are like *gold*, often pinpointing your error. Study them. None of these comments are criticisms. We're just trying to help you learn.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There are versions of SO in various languages, which might help: "[Do posts have to be in English on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange)". "Doesn't work" tells us nothing that lets us help you, as others said. Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" which explain the issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `print` method is a bit messed up and it is calling a `months` variable, which doesn't exist.

Test dataset, just in case anybody finds it useful:

```
students = [{:name=>"Peter", :cohort=>"A", :country_of_birth=>"Here"}, {:name=>"Popeye", :cohort=>"A", :country_of_birth=>"There"}, {:name=>"Tom", :cohort=>"A", :country_of_birth=>"Where"}, {:name=>"Jack", :cohort=>"J", :country_of_birth=>"Here"}, {:name=>"Ron", :cohort=>"J", :country_of_birth=>"There"}, {:name=>"Ross", :cohort=>"R", :country_of_birth=>"Anywhere"}]
```

Try something like this, using [Array#select](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-select):

```
def my_print(students)
  puts "What cohort would you like to print"
  cohort_input = gets.chomp#.capitalize
  students.select{ |s| s[:cohort] == cohort_input }.each {|student| p student }
end
```

Side note, don't use `print` as method name.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, it works perfectly, but what if the input is not a month, how can I make sure that the input goes through only if a month is given. 
I need an if statement but also the months must be in an array, no?

Comment: It’ a quite broad question. You could store months in an array and use `include?` consider to post a new question if you get stuck.